# The website encountered an error while retrieving omniauth-google-oauth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I'm working on a website and doing social media logins for `facebook` and `google`. `Facebook` works fine on `development` & `production` but when i try to login with google it throws error

> server error : 500
>
> The website encountered an error while retrieving
>   http://app.domain.com/omniauth/google_oauth2/callback?state=abc. It
>   may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

and my logs show me this (below)

> I, [2016-03-17T06:]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Request phase
>   initiated. I, [2016-03-17T06:]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2)
>   Callback phase initiated.

I searched about this and they all saying that this can be due to some `plugin` (#in my case `gems`) incompatibality . My `Gemfile` looks like this

**GemFile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'rails-api'
gem 'spring', :group => :development
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'byebug'

gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_token_auth'

gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
gem 'carrierwave'
#gem 'carrierwave-base64-storage'
gem 'carrierwave-base64'
gem 'rmagick' 

gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'

gem 'httparty'
gem 'rpush'
```

Same thing is working on `localhost`(`development mode`) . But not on live server (`production mode`) .And i'm pretty sure that `redirect urls` set on `Google developer console` is correct because it's hitting on server after redirect (as shown in logs above) .I'm also sure about `routes` as they are handling the response in development mode .I also give a shot to `Bundle update` , But , no use

Answer (score 0):

My only thought is that there's some route that configured for your localhost and not for production. Could you post your routes?

I set up google oauth by following this blog (https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/09/gmail-api-oauth-rails.html) so if you can't figure it out walking though that might help